# How can I prevent a wasp entering the house?

Tags: pest-control

I leave very high up and yet there are many wasps entering. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install window/door nets. If you can't afford that a curtain should do the trick (with the end of it attached to the bottom frame, so that the draught does not blow it around).

From what you descride you probably have a wasp nest nearby (or there is a vast increase in wasp population in the area but in that case they would be everywhere). Well, you could prevent the wasps from entering if you find and destroy their nest, but unless you are allergic I wouldn't advise you to have it destroyed - wasps are alright to live around with and they won't do anything to you unless you attack them.

Comment: In addition to this useful solution, you can hang "fly strips" near each window in case any wasps sneak past the screen or curtain. In case you haven't heard of fly strips before, they are strips of extremely adhesive tape. When flying insects land on them, they get stuck and die.